# LL_ALLOCATED_SPACE and other considerations

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, kernel

I have a kernel module wherein I capture a packet in PRE-ROUTING hook for some processing. I then allocate a new skb(cant do it in the same skb) and put the processed payload of the input skb and the ip header in this new skb. I would then want to do a netif_rx for this new skb and let it traverse the kernel networking stack.

I am little confused with the size of the new skb I should allocate, where my skb->data should point to (to network_header or mac header). What should be the skb->len, should it consider mac header or not?

```
len; // total length of new ip datagram
skb_new = dev_alloc_skb(len + LL_ALLOCATED_SPACE(skb->dev) + ETH_LEN);
```

after this how much should I reserve for LL header and trailer and where should my skb_new->data point to.

I want to call netif_rx(skb_new) after filling in the required details in skb. Basically what should follow after allocating the skb and before calling netif_rx.
Any link or description will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A socket buffer (skb) holds *ALL* of the information for the current protocol data unit (PDU) and accounts for *ALL* of the data being passed around for this PDU.  Regardless of how much slack space you leave at the beginning of the skb, you point your `skb->data` to the beginning of *YOUR* data.